# "He did lettuce of ham-glazing a-cheese-mints."

Tags: word-play

This sentence is from the question corner (also known as *[SBS](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS)*) of Volume 10 of *One Piece*:

[image]

Transcript:

> Q: When Patty the Cook says "I'm turniply saucy," what does it mean?
>
> A: "I'm terribly sorry." He tends to make things sound like food. For example, he might say: "He's quite a man. He did lettuce of ham-glazing a-cheese-mints. Peas apple-aud him." But if *you* say thing like that, people will probably look at you funny.

I understand that this is a joke/wordplay, and that the translator was perhaps doing a free translation, since [this other translation](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_10#Chapter_89,_Page_168) I found on the wiki is very different.

"Peas apple-aud him" probably means "Please applaud him", which fits the first sentence "He's quite a man". What about the second sentence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about learning English. It's about "insanely creative" wordplay that would baffle most native Anglophones

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a unique translation of a Japanese cartoon/story.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Translation doesn't really seem to have a bearing on the question; it's just punning. 10Seconds, note, puns are always a problem in translations. In one language, two words sound similar, but their equivalents in another language don't. That's why you might find a very different translation; one might be a literal translation of a Japanese pun, while another tries to replicate the effect by choosing English words that do sound similar.

Comment: @AndyBonner  I agree that most translations are dependent on whether or not they are  faithful to the original text. That's why this question  is off-topic, we have no way of knowing unless someone is a Japanese native speaker and tell us. The OP is asking what the sentence: **He did lettuce of ham-glazing a-cheese-mints** means.  It's  nonsense, reminiscent of Lewis Carol's Jabberwock but at least he was English. At a guess the word "**lettuce of**" would represent ***let us of***, the rest is anyone's guess. coneslayer has probably guessed it right.

Comment: A problem with these cute mistranslations is the hidden or not-so-hidden ridicule inherent in laughing at, not with, accents.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I have seen in 1950s American literature, bigoted hayseeds being made to say things like 'gubmint' and 'cuminisks' (government and communists respectively) which probably pleased the writer and many of the readers, but looks kind of stupid now. W Somerset Maugham made Chinese people say things like 'me glavedigger at cemetery', and one used to see plenty of British authors sneering at rural or regional accents by phonetically 'representing' them, especially Cockney. 'Naow, guv, git aout o' me way!'.

Comment: *T'was brillig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe* might be "nonsense", but at least it sounds as though if you knew all those nouns and verbs, it *would* be meaningful. But *He did lettuce of ham-glazing a-cheese-mints* just looks like "syntactic salad" as well as irregularly-constructed derivatives of semantically weird random terms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the German one is fun: _»Bewahre doch vor Jammerwoch!
Die Zähne knirschen, Krallen kratzen!
Bewahr' vor Jubjub-Vogel, vor
Frumiösen Banderschntzchen!«_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: But do they translate ***wabe***? I just checked, and that's in the full OED. Defined as *A factitious word introduced by ‘Lewis Carroll’* - so if you didn't know it's the grassy plot by the sundial, you could read Carroll's poem to find that. But Google tells me that's just what the characters in the poem mistakenly assert, whereas Carroll in his original Mischmasch text stated that ***a 'wabe' is "the side of a hill (from its being soaked by rain)".*** Live and learn!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, I disagree; Coneslayer's answer seems obvious. The passage isn't terribly well done or clever, and stretches itself so hard that it becomes difficult, but the intent seems clear. It's not a question about translation, just about how to read an admittedly poorly executed joke.

Comment: @AndyBonner - 'poorly executed' - that's being generous. Annoyingly and stupidly infantile. In real life we would either avoid such a person, or strongly advise them to see treatment for their clearly worsening mental health.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess "He did lots of amazing achievements."

Comment: That seems plausible, but we don't 'do' achievements, do we? I know that's on the author, not you!